# Copying part of a large file using command line

Tags: shell, scripting

I've a text file with 2 million lines. Each line has some transaction information.

e.g.

> 23848923748, sample text, feild2 , 12/12/2008

etc

What I want to do is create a new file from a certain unique transaction number onwards. So I want to split the file at the line where this number exists.

How can I do this form the command line?

I can find the line by doing this:

```
cat myfile.txt | grep 23423423423
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a random file in my `tmp` directory, this is how I output everything from the line matching `popd` onwards in a file named `tmp.sh`:

```
tail -n+`grep -n popd tmp.sh | cut -f 1 -d:` tmp.sh
```

`tail -n+X` matches from that line number onwards; `grep -n`  outputs lineno:filename, and cut extracts just `lineno` from `grep`.

So for your case it would be:

```
 tail -n+`grep -n 23423423423 myfile.txt | cut -f 1 -d:` myfile.txt
```

And it should indeed match from the first occurrence onwards.

Comment: well to be more specific this worked
    tail -n+`grep -n 23423423423 myfile.txt | cut -f 1 -d:` myfile.txt > newfile.txt

Comment: @Derek, I was surprised to see you preferred a tail+grep+cut over a simple stream edit...

Comment: @nik i''m sure yours works as well but i actually understood this one.  so its my lack of knowledge that made me choose this answer.  In saying that this worked as expected and quickly.

Answer (score 3):

use [`sed`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-30) like this

```
sed '/23423423423/,$!d' myfile.txt
```

Just confirm that the unique transaction number cannot appear as a pattern in some other part of the line (especially, before the correctly matching line) in your file.

---

There is already a '`perl`' answer here, so, i'll give one more **AWK** way :-)

```
awk '{BEGIN{skip=1} /number/ {skip=0} // {if (skip!=1) print $0}' myfile.txt
```

Comment: it shouldn't appear twice but just in case it did, how could I amend it so it works from the first occurrence to the end of the file.

Comment: Get some constant pattern that will qualify the match to be occurring only with the transaction number. Like is the number first thing on the line? (then, match "^number"), Is it prefixed or suffixed with a whitespace or say the ':' character? (try "number:", etc).

Comment: `awk '/23423423423/,0{print}'` is shorter -- in fact, you can even throw out `{print}`, as that's the default action.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a pretty solution, but how about using `-A` parameter of grep?

Like this:

```
mc@zolty:/tmp$ cat a
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
mc@zolty:/tmp$ cat a | grep 3 -A1000000
3
4
5
6
7
```

The only problem I see in this solution is the `1000000` magic number. Probably someone will know the answer without using such a trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get the line number using Grep and then use Tail to print the file from that point into your output file.

Sorry I don't have actual code to show, but hopefully the idea is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a quick Perl script, frankly. It's invaluable for anything like this (relatively simple issues) and as soon as something more complex rears its head (as it will do!) then you'll need the extra power.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/perl

my $out = 0;
while (<STDIN>) {
   if /23423423423/ then $out = 1;
   print $_ if $out;
}
```

and run it using:

```
$ perl mysplit.pl < input > output
```

Not tested, I'm afraid.

Comment: Shorter: perl -ne 'print if /23423423423/ .. eof()'

Comment: That's better. I was aware you could do that but had forgotten the details etc.

Comment: I modified this slightly to get it to work (and also to ignore case if searching for a text string). I changed the if statement to:
 if ($_ =~/stevens/i) { $out = 1;}
Hope that's of interest to someone..